# What pattern to use to be more flexible?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am building an interface to read, validate, convert and store data. In this way two systems can cummunicate with each other.

I have created a generic flow which works fine and is very extensible:

- IProcessor< P, S> -> Proces() : void
- IProvider -> GetItems() : IEnumerable< string>
- IValidator -> Validate(string) : void
- IParser< P > -> Parse(string) : P
- IMapper< P, S> -> Map(P) : S
- IStorage< S> -> Save(S)
- new Processor(IProvider, IValidator, IParser< P>, IMapper< P, S>, IStorage< S>)

The problem is that there is a business rule which states that P must be mapped to S1 or S2 depending on a Value. How to alter the structure, so that it is more flexible?

Comment: What is `P`? What is `S1` or `S2`?

Comment: This seems like a test question...

Comment: Are you re-building BizTalk?  Writing an interface engine is rarely a good use of time when so many pre-built ones are available.

Answer (score 0):

Add an interface:

- `IBusinessRule<P, S>` -> `MapToS1(P) : bool`

Initialize mapper with it:

- `new Mapper(IBusinessRule<P, S>)`

P.S. I mean that `S1 : S` and `S2 : S`.